# prevent XSS without htmlspecialchars

Tags: php

I need to prevent XSS but without `htmlspecialchars / htmlspecialchars_decode` now i use `str_replace`

this code is good or not complete ?

```
$secret = str_replace('<', '', $secret);
$secret = str_replace('>', '', $secret);
```

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use `htmlspecialchars()`? Also `htmlentities()` would be an option.

Comment: For what purpose? Escaping/filtering makes no sense without knowing about the target context. What's the rationale behind eschewing the recommended approach? "I need dis" is an insufficient explanation.

Comment: Use `filter_var` in PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: That's like asking "I need to screw in a screw without a screwdriver".

Comment: Its for crypt a array and with htmlspecialchars i have always bug

Comment: Then you're doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter_var is better than your current code:

```
filter_var($secret, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

`FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS`: HTML-escape `'"<>&` and characters with ASCII value less than 32, optionally strip or encode other special characters.

Comment: Please check the return output in your code if it also provide enough protection against XSS by escaping properly. There are many more validation and sanitation filters to be found on `php.net` http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php